# Without IDE-like feature, how do we know where package-level variables are defined?

Tags: go

In Go, "top level" variables have package-level scope and files don't really have any meaning in terms of scope. No concept of "module" like in python, javascript(es6), etc. (Well, there is "go module", but it's more like "package" in these languages and it's not related here, I think.)

If so, how do we know where variables are defined without IDE/editor's help? I feel it's like I'm managing a large set of global variables. For example:

```
// foo.go
package main

var foo = "foo"
```

```
// bar.go
package main

var bar = "bar"
```

```
// main.go
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(foo, bar)
}
```

Here, how do we know where `foo` and `bar` come from, in case I couldn't use today's rich editor feature and if the project had a huge codebase? I actually feel it's already difficult to follow `foo` and `bar` even in this case.

Comment: if you use any variable with import statement then you can assume its local variable

Comment: Do like you did with C 25 years ago.

Comment: There's no magic - either you have the tools and you use them or you don't and you can't. There are multiple IDEs for Go (GoLand, VSCode, Atom, vim-go, etc) that can provide this sort of functionality. If you can't use one of them, then you won't have IDE features and you'll have to resort to something like `grep`.

Comment: What would be the reason to have that information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using terminal with no GUI? If you do not have access to an IDE, all I can think about is using Linux command like `grep` to search in a lot of files inside of the package folder for `var <variableName>` terms.

If you have a package named `test` with 100 files and you want to know where `boo` top-level package variable is, then do:

```sh
grep -nw /path/to/test/*.go -e '^var boo'
```

Explanation:

- `-n` to output the line number
- `-w` stands for whole word
- `-e` is for the pattern

Using `/*.go` instead of `-r` flag to make sure that it searches only in `.go` files in the top level directory, (not searching inside the sub-packages too).

WARNING: this assumes that all files are correctly formatted with `gofmt` for example and all package variables are not indented. If by accident the variable gets indented with spaces/tabs then you can just omit `^` in the pattern, but this will probably find `var boo` local variables inside functions as well.

If a package has too many package-level variables and the package is large, then it could be a problem. Top-level variables are like globals, which are better avoided unless you know what to do.

By the way, doing `go build -v` or running other tools with `-v` will output extra information like the packages that are built along. This might help you do your searching.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to look at all the libraries you're importing, generally in Golang you'd put all things relating to a particular set of functionality into a single package. You might prefix all functionality in a library with something or use a certain namespace to make this easier.

Answer (score 0):

`godoc -http=:6060` in your project folder. Make sure it is a `go-module` or is inside you `$GOPATH/src`

And then `http://localhost:6060/pkg/<your-package>?m=all` is a local documentation for all exported and unexported symbols.

While this will still not give you the mapping for variables to files directly - it makes it much easier to discover.

Everything else(functions,methods...) in the documentation are linked directly to their source